# Change Windows Store Region

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I live in India but I would like to view and purchase the apps available in US.

Is there any way to change the region of the Windows Store in Windows 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.
2. Type `region`.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Select the `Location` tab.
5. Change the home location to the country of which you want to view and purchase apps:

   [image]
6. Done.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

See, I was able to access about 550+ apps after changing the region.

Comment: Note: You may run into issues using a billing address/credit card from one region with another region set.   See [Roaming in Windows 8. Switching Between Country/Region. Using Apps Purchased in a Different Country/Region](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w8itprogeneral/thread/11362473-be7e-41dc-baa8-8e42cccb0ba0)

Comment: Wow Microsoft managed to make this experience even worse than in the iOS / Mac App Store >.<

Comment: Remember also about changing language (on Administrativ tab lower button) if You have difrent from desired region (eg U.S. ) .