# How to access AppStore from Windows 8 in unsupported region?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

I am from Myanmar and I am now using Windows 8. The Windows 8 App Store is not supported in our country, but still I would like to open and download applications from it.

So, how can I access App Store?

Comment: One solution would be to use a proxy.

Comment: Also see [Change Windows Store Region](http://superuser.com/questions/499557/change-windows-store-region)

Answer (score 4):

This really is a matter of legality.  Microsoft does not permit regions to access the app-store unless they are able to sell the apps legally in that country.

Reasons they cannot sell apps can include everything from issues with tax-collection, export fees and even laws against exporting of security technology.  Asking us for instructions on how-to circumvent this goes against the Terms of Service for this site..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Proxy software like Ultrasulf. I'm also from Myanmar and by using Ultrasulf, I can now access Store and can download. But you need to have a good connection.

Good Luck Bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I' m also from Myanmar.
I changed Windows Store Region and I work on my laptop.
(my first location was US and I changed to Myanmar)